# Can't see my fragment using ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to use ActionBarSherlock to display different listfragments depending on which tab is currently being viewed. So far though I can't even get past trying to display my fragment. I can see that it's getting instantiated and created but it's not being displayed at all in the view.

Here's the activity that I have that implements SherlockFragmentActivity:

```
public class MyListView extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(com.actionbarsherlock.R.style.Theme_Sherlock); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);

        MyListFrag listFrag = (MyListFrag) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment1);          
        listFrag.update(ViewActivity.livePoints);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment1, listFrag);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);

            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

}
```

You can see I've tried to add the fragment to the activity by using a fragmentmanager but I'm also trying to add it through xml which isn't working for me at the moment either.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="20dip">


<fragment
    android:name="core.MyListFrag"
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally here's my listfragment class that I'm using. What I'm trying to do is populate the list with a custom adapter that I create by extending baseadapter but I'm not sure if I'm doing that correctly which could be a part of the problem.

```
public class MyListFrag extends SherlockListFragment{

MarkItemAdapter mia;

@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  mia = new MarkItemAdapter(this.getActivity(), MyViewActivity.livePoints);
  setListAdapter(mia);
  Toast.makeText(getSherlockActivity(), "frag started"+MyViewActivity.livePoints.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_frag_layout, container, false);


}

public void updateUrl(List<Points> newList) {
    if(mia!=null){
        mia.points.clear();
        mia.points = newList;
        mia.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
        mia.points = newList;
        mia.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

class MarkItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    List<Points> points = null;
    Context cntx = null;
    LayoutInflater myInflater;
    int itemPosition =0;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public MarkItemAdapter(Context cntx,List<Points> points){

        this.points = points;
        this.cntx = cntx;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return marks.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        itemPosition = position;

        if (convertView==null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.point_row_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.point_description);
            holder.distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.point_distance);
            holder.point_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.point_image);
            holder.view_point = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.view_mark);
            holder.rate_point = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rate_point);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.description.setText(points.get(itemPosition).title);
        holder.distance.setText(points.get(itemPosition).getDistanceString());
        holder.view_point.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                //do stuff
            }

        });

    //add logic for rating bar

        return convertView;
    }


}

private class MyViewHolder{
    ImageView mark_image;
    TextView description;
    TextView distance;
    ImageButton view_mark;
    RatingBar rate_mark;
}

}
```

I could add the other XML layouts if that helps anyone to help me out but I left them out as I'm pretty sure it's my Java that's the problem and not the layout. Fragments are definitely not very straightforward when you first use them. I'm not sure if I have to use `onAttach()` or not or something else and looking over the Android documentation and seeing all the other tutorials has me totally confused at the moment. From playing around with fragments before I know I'm close so I don't want to throw together ten tutorials in a mess of code just to get a Frankenstein fragment going.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the xml file you posted is the **R.layout.tab_navigation** it seems ok

if you don't have error like "class not found..." or "error inflating layout..."   it is fine

The idea of using fragment is having and activity (SherlockFragmentActivity) that is a **container**,  and children (fragment) that you can **add/replace** when rotating the screen or using a tablet in order to have a flexible interface.

This way can also be used to have master/detail flow such as **albumList->imageList->slideShow**

So you have your MyListView that play the role of **container** and inflate the xml you posted **R.layout.tab_navigation**. And the class MyListFrag that will replace the balise **fragment** and itself inflate **R.layout.list_frag_layout**

Now when using fragment you should consider using **replace** instead of **add**

One question, what do you want to use fragment for (in this case) ?